# mysql update column values with replace

Tags: mysql

one of my table contains column path stores the URL example:\xyz\attachments, \abc\attachments, etc total i have 16 combinations to replace

i found rows by using rlike in where clause 'abc|xyz|'

have to update xyz with xxx or abc with yyyy

i am not sure how to update these part of the values of column. Is it possible using single query or i have to write 16 queries to do that? please advise here

Comment: Please decide whether you are using mysql or pl/sql (associated with Oracle) and tag your question appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not reliable, but is doable. Basically nested `replace()` calls:

```
UPDATE ... 
SET yourfield = REPLACE(REPLACE(yourfield, '\\xyz', 'newtext'), '\\abc', 'othertext')
```

Note that if `xyz` or `abc` can appear in multiple places in either string, you may end up replacing something that shouldn't have been.